# How to disabled or non-editable text editor using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, rich-text-editor, richtext

I am using a [rich text editor](https://richtexteditor.com/) on my portal. Is there any way not to edit this without permission from the admin? I mean can we disabled it?

I also testing this [jQuery rich text](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Rich-Text-Editor-jQuery-RichText.html)

I tried the below code but it's still allowing me to edit.

HTML

```
  <textarea class="contenteditor1 disabledme" name="message"  hidden="hidden"><?php echo $info['message'];?></textarea>
```

jquery

```
$('.disabledme').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Yes, of course. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is this even related to CSS?

Comment: @NicoHaase, wait I am sharing the code which I tried.  2min

Comment: @NicoHaase, I added jquery to disabled, readonly,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What does the given code do? What is not working yet?

Comment: @NicoHaase, The code which I tried that I added in the question. and I just clicked on the editor and it's allowing me to edit.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please add what you've tried to disable editing - what does the documentation of that plugin tell you about this? If this is not listed there, you should better ask their support whether this is possible or not

Comment: @NicoHaase, I apologize for my bad, I'll take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look rich text editor HomePage you will know that there is a future `ReadOnly`

```
 editor1.setReadOnly(true);
```

This will disable the textEditor.

Read more about this [here](https://richtexteditor.com/demos/readonly.aspx)

Comment: so i have to use editor1=$('.contenteditor1').richText();

Comment: Hmm look at thair API Demos it says `var editor1 = new RichTextEditor("#div_editor1");`

Comment: Ok. let me check... also can you check this plugin also? https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Rich-Text-Editor-jQuery-RichText.html

Comment: There is no documentation on this but I looked at their script and there is no feature to disable this. You will have to download their script and add this feature. it should be easy

Comment: Sorry the code should be ` editor1.setReadOnly(true);` false will enable this

Comment: Ok. Yes, I checked there is no documentation even I also checked the feature. I downloaded all the script but where should i add the feature and what feature I have to add?

Comment: Ok will try to make this very simple without editing the script. When you create the RichText, it will create a div with class `richText-editor` that contain `contenteditable="true"` then you simple execute this query `$(".richText-editor").attr("contenteditable", false)`. and that is all you need to do to make it not editable

Comment: Give me sometime to check

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper solution, you need to edit the few lines of code:

1. First in your main index.html file you have to pass two arguments, one blank and one with either true or false, true means editable and false means not editable.

$('.content').richText('',false);

2. Than in your jquery.richtext.js file on line at 27 add one more argument (iseditable) in function like below:

$.fn.richText = function (options,iseditable) {

3. Than on same jquery.richtext.js file at line 535  replace the whole line with the below code like this:

var $editorView = $('', {class: "richText-editor", id: editorID, contenteditable: iseditable});

Answer (score 0):

to set readonly true

```
    data.attr("readonly",true);
```

to set readonly false

```
    data.attr("readonly",false);
```